# gradle not downloading dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle

New to gradle, and I'm tryig to replace maven as a build tool.
I've added Jsoup as a dependency in gradle, and tried to have it downloaded, but its not downloading it into the project.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    //jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile ('org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2')
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and the output i get when I run gradle clean build
[image]

Jsoup does not get downloaded, isn't showing in the output and I cannot use it. However, it will download in maven without issue.

Am I missing something?

Comment: try to remove the brackets          compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'

Comment: gradle dependencies are only downloaded the first time, and are fetched from the cache in subsequent runs - which means the download line may not show up on the command line. (you can force re download with `--refresh-dependencies`. Can  you run `gradle dependencies` and post the output?

Comment: It seemed to show up after i ran `gradle dependencies` and rebooted eclipse

Comment: @mcgowan.b did you fix it? I am having trouble. With Pom.XML it automatically adds all the dependencies. But with gradle I just have errors